# Adding multiple onclick elements in a shoping cart

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add new elements in my cart object, when click on a button for shopping that product

I've created a object p2, and a "cart" which will contain what someone wants to purchase. When onclick the button "add-on-cart", should add as many p2 objects as we click on it

js:

```
let p2 = new Product("pencil", 3, 0, 10);
let cart = new ShoppingCart();
//addProduct is a function inside cart class
addProduct(product) {
    this.products.push(product);
    this.products.sort();
};
document.getElementById("buttonpen").addEventListener("click", cart.addProduct(p2))
```

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonpen">Purchase</button>
```

The expected result would be if I click 4 times the button, my array product is filled with 4 pen. What happens is that when I open the browser it push 1 pen by itself, and don't keep pushing new ones as I click on the button

Comment: @Grafluxe I've tried what you said and now it works perfectly. Thanks so much! I will look into currying, seems something I've been missing. Thank you!

Comment: Please add the solution you found as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing a product added as soon as the page loads is because you're *calling* the function in your listener (instead of *passing* it in).

Since you focused on a small aspect of your project, it's hard to give you details on how to better approach your problem. Based on your current implementation, you can update your listener to be the following:

```
document.getElementById("buttonpen").addEventListener("click", () => cart.addProduct(p2));
```

You can also look into `currying` in JS.